# Looking for an Apple - iOS application which does emotional analysis

Tags: ios, social-networks

I want to learn some socio technical software systems for emotional analysis for iOS applications. For Android, there is one called "mental" but it doesn't have any version for iOS yet. And "mappiness" for iOS is not enough for me.

I want to measure my facebook, whatsapp, etc. applications' usage times with feelings.